# What is the opposite of loud in the context of alarm or phone ringtone etc.?

Tags: word-choice

What word should I use to describe something that is not very loud?
for example

> I am sick of his loud alarm, it always wakes me up.

Should I use *light alarm* or ringtone or something else?

Comment: [_Quiet_ and its synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/quiet)?

Comment: I GET ANNOYED WHEN PEOPLE YELL LOUDLY WITH ALL CAPS. Especially when they obnoxiously attempt to ALARM me. It would be more effective if they wrote to me in the gentle quietness of usual lower case, and only YELL occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the terms "soft" or "gentle".

Answer (score 1):

You can use either calm or soft!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I would go for *hushed*, *muffled* or *subdued*.

**Eg:** This darn alarm is so ***hushed/muffled/subdued*** that I can hardly hear it!

Answer (score 1):

In the context of phone ringtones (and TV remote controls) it increasingly means *silent*, rather than *of low sound volume*, but...

> [muted](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbo=u&q=muted&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=7IEKUbGQKpDL0AXfxoHwCQ&ved=0CC4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.d2k&fp=c4bf0c461ac69915&biw=1351&bih=889) *- (of a sound or voice) quiet and soft*

...seems potentially appropriate to me *("...I wish he'd get an alarm with a more muted tone.")*

As can be seen from many instances of [the muted tones of](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20muted%20tones%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, besides the literal sense, it's also often used figuratively (of pastel colours, subdued lighting, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest *unobtrusive*

> [***unobtrusive***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unobtrusive) : Not undesirably noticeable or blatant; inconspicuous.

Since I expect that to be in any way effective, the alarm must still be audible. Otherwise at the far other end of the spectrum from loud is *inaudible*.